# Looking for a post hoc for a type 2 Anova (mixed-effects model)

Tags: r, lme4, anova, mixed-models, r-car

My question is how do I run a post hoc on a type 2 Anova (mixed-effects model)? So far I am using the `glmer()` from the "lme4" package, the `Anova()` from the "car" package, and trying to run a HSD test from the "agricolae" package.

After searching for some time this is the best that I could find, however, I receive an error message when doing so. Does anyone know how to get around this or what I am doing wrong? Or a different way of doing this?

```
library(lme4)
totaldiversity.model <- glmer(totaldiversity ~ focalspecies + (1|site), family = "poisson", data = data, na.action=na.fail)
library(car)
totaldiv.anova = Anova(totaldiversity.model, type = "II")
library(agricolae)
totaldiv.tukey = HSD.test(totaldiv.anova, "focalspecies", group=TRUE, console=TRUE)
```

Error message that comes up: `Error in HSD.test(totaldiv.anova, "focalspecies", group = TRUE, console = TRUE,  : argument "MSerror" is missing, with no default`

Thank you in advance!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31013260/post-hoc-test-for-glmer

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/145765/post-hoc-testing-in-multcompglht-for-mixed-effects-models-lme4-with-interact

Comment: Thank you @BenBolker! This is what I did and it looks like it worked 
`totaldiversity.model <- glmer(totaldiversity ~ focalspecies + (1|site), family = "poisson", data = data, na.action=na.fail)
totaldiv.anova = Anova(totaldiversity.model, type = "II")
summary(glht(totaldiversity.model, mcp(focalspecies="Tukey")))`

Comment: if you solved your own problem, you're encouraged to answer it yourself (there may be a waiting period)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed the link posted by Ben Bolker ([Post-hoc test for glmer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31013260/post-hoc-test-for-glmer)) which led me to use the `glht()` function in the multcomp package. This is what the solution looked like for a multiple comparisons analysis (Tukey) on a `glmer()` mixed effects model, with a type 2 Anova. Need "multcomp", "lme4", and "car" packages.

```
totaldiversity.model <- glmer(totaldiversity ~ focalspecies + (1|site), family = "poisson", data = data, na.action=na.fail)
summary(totaldiversity.model)
Anova(totaldiversity.model, type = "II")
summary(glht(totaldiversity.model, mcp(focalspecies="Tukey")))
```

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score -1):

From the documentation for `HSD.test`, `y` is "model(aov or lm) or answer of the experimental unit". In all likelihood this means you should be sending it `totaldiversity.model`:

```
HSD.test(totaldiversity.model, "focalspecies", group=TRUE, console=TRUE)
```

Comment: If I change it to model then this error comes up: "Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE) : 
  cannot coerce class "structure("glmerMod", package = "lme4")" to a data.frame"